# Nest api connectivity issue

Tags: nest-api

I've tried all of the steps in the instructions, but always get an error at #5 when it is supposed to redirect to google.com.
https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/authorize#link_your_account

The error:

Authorization Error
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, https://www.google.com, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: [https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/${your_client_id}?project=${your_project_number}](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/$%7Byour_client_id%7D?project=$%7Byour_project_number%7D)

I've ensured I have the right numbers- without spaces in the url and have put it in notepad and deleted all of the returns so it is one line of text.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What do you have listed in the Authorized Redirect URIs for your OAuth client in GCP, and what is the exact PCM URL you used?  You shouldn't get this error if the `redirect_uri` and `client_id` parameters in the PCM URL matches what you have in GCP for the client.